# I've created a variable which is supposed to generate random number between 0 and 4 but it is only showing the output as 1

Tags: javascript

```
 var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() *3);
```

Output
[image]

Comment: The variable `randomNumber` stores the result of the random calculation, so it doesn't change as you're logging the one stored value. You need to re-execute `Math.floor(Math.random() *3);` everytime you want a new random number (this could be done by wrapping this code in it's own function)

Comment: The value of your `variable` is only initialized **once**, it won't update each time you log it, you should use a `function` instead of a variable if you want it to take a new `value` in each call.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, it doesn't need real answers as it is just a wrong understanding and a confusion between variables and functions in JS

Comment: Also this won't even give you numbers from 0-4, itll give you 0-2

Answer (score 1):

randomNumber should be a function which returns a number. Right now it is just a variable that has been assigned a value once and you are logging the same value.

```js
 var randomNumber = () => Math.floor(Math.random() *3);
 console.log(randomNumber());
  console.log(randomNumber());
   console.log(randomNumber());
    console.log(randomNumber());
```

Answer (score 0):

Though in the question there's a misunderstanding of how variables in JS work, it's possible to do very near to something similar with JS by using objects.

All objects have a method named `valueOf`, which returns the primitive value of the object when it's needed. This method is often called internally when JS makes implicit type conversions. This method can also be overridden, you can write your own `valueOf` method, and JS will use that method instead of the built-in method. Like this:

```js
// RandomNumberGenratorFactory
function randomNumber(min, max, dec) {
  // min: The lower limit of the rnd <Number>
  // max: The upper limit of the rnd <Number>
  // dec: The count of decimals of the rnd <Integer>
  //      dec > 0, if int <= 0 or omitted, an integer rnd will be returned

  // Swap min/max if needed
  if (max < min) {
    [max, min] = [min, max];
  }
  // Prepare to create an integer rnd
  let fn = Math.floor,
    fix = 1;
  if (dec > 0) {
    // Prepare to create a decimal rnd
    fn = x => +x.toFixed(dec);
    fix = 0;
  }
  return {
    // Shadows the original valueOf method
    valueOf: () => fn(Math.random() * (max - min + fix) + min)
  };
}

// Create random number generators
const rnd = randomNumber(-4, 4),
  rnD = randomNumber(1, 5, 3);

// The generator variable itself refers to an object
console.log(rnd);

for (let n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
  // Getting numeric value of the generators by unary plus operator
  const r = +rnd;
  console.log(r, +rnD);
}

// Generator evaluates to a number when used with operators
console.log(rnD + rnd - rnD * rnd);
```

The reason why your code didn't work, is that `Math.floor(Math.random() *3);` returns a primitive (a number in this case), and primitives are just values, they're not linked to the expression or function which originally created the value.